# Can I modify the sql query generated by values() before it gets executed in django

Tags: sql, django, database, postgresql, django-queryset

I wanna modify the queries generated by django before it gets executed in database, is it possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using class-based-views you can use def `get_queryset(self)` on your view and put your code into it

here is the documentation: https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.10/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/